# PHP AWS SDK 3 Error: AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: s3.oregon.amazonaws.com

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to connect to an AWS version 3 SDK bucket.

But, I receive the below error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.oregon.amazonaws.com/my-buekct-test/hello_world.txt"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: s3.oregon.amazonaws.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'

This is my code, just simple.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'region'  => 'Oregon',
'version' => 'latest',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => 'Enter the key',
    'secret' => 'Enter the Secret key'
]
]);

// Send a PutObject request and get the result object.
$key = 'hello_world.txt';

$result = $s3->putObject([
'Bucket' => 'my-buekct-test',
'Key'    => $key,
'Body'   => 'this is the body!'
]);

// Print the body of the result by indexing into the result object.
echo $result['Body'];
```

I'm using AWS centos, php 5.5.21, apache 2.4.10

Could you help point out where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with below code you need to change region only

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'region'  => 'us-west-2',
'version' => 'latest',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => 'Enter the key',
    'secret' => 'Enter the Secret key'
]
]);

// Send a PutObject request and get the result object.
$key = 'hello_world.txt';

$result = $s3->putObject([
'Bucket' => 'my-buekct-test',
'Key'    => $key,
'Body'   => 'this is the body!'
]);

// Print the body of the result by indexing into the result object.
echo $result['Body'];
```

> 'region'  => 'us-west-2', // this thing i only updated

you can find region information of aws from here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Hope this will help!