# S3::putObject(): [6] Could not resolve host: http

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

I am uploading image on Amazon S3 through codeigniter. My S3Url, secret key and access key is right. But still i am getting following error in S3 library.

```
S3::putObject(): [6] Could not resolve host: http
```

Even I have given AmazonS3FullAccess permission to my bucket. But still getting same error. 
I have tried my best but still didnt getting solution. Please help me in this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Did you set the region?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991171/3585500)

Comment: Yes. My region is singapore.

Comment: It would be good if you can provide code snippet that tried to connect and upload to S3 and probably complete error you are getting.